# Masking raw pointer (Rust)

Tags: pointers, rust, qemu, nic

I'm writing code to interface with the NIC in my emulator (QEMU). I need to write the high and low 32-bits of my descriptor array to two separate addresses in memory. I'm struggling to mask (and shift) my raw pointer to write both halves to memory.

I have:

```
#[repr(align(16))]
struct e1000_rx_desc {
    address : u64,
    length : u16,
    checksum : u16,
    status : u8,
    errors : u8,
    special : u16,
}
```

And:

```
#[repr(align(16))]
struct e1000_tx_desc {
    address : u64,
    length : u16,
    cso : u8,
    cmd : u8,
    status : u8,
    css : u8,
    special : u16,
}
```

An array of these descriptors is stored inside:

```
pub struct E1000 {
    base : u32,
    rx : [*mut e1000_rx_desc; 32],
    tx : [*mut e1000_tx_desc; 8],
}
```

And I've been attempting to write to the hardware registers with:

```
self.write_u32_to_register(Registers::REG_RX_DESC_LO, 0, ((&self.rx as **mut e1000_rx_desc) & 0xFFFFFFFF) as u32);
self.write_u32_to_register(Registers::REG_RX_DESC_HI, 0, ((&self.rx as **mut e1000_rx_desc) >> 32) as u32);
```

I get the following error:

```
no implementation for `*const *mut e1000::e1000_rx_desc & {integer}
```

What is the best way to get access to the raw address so I can manipulate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers can be cast to and from a `usize` using the `as` operator:

```
let x: i32 = 5;
let x_ptr: *const i32 = &x as *const i32;
let x_ptr_addr: usize = x_ptr as usize;
let new_ptr = (x_ptr_addr & 0xffff) as *const i32;
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. But can you please explain the `&0xffff` part ?

Comment: @WatashiJ OP's original issue is that they wanted to `&` the pointer with an integer but couldn't, so I threw in an `& 0xffff` to demonstrate that it works.